# How to repeat list's elements with each different n times and in Python?

Tags: python, list, iterator

The idea is to repeat list's elements with each different `n` times as below.

```
ls = [7, 3, 11, 5, 2, 3, 4, 4, 2, 3]
id_list_fname = ['S11', 'S15', 'S16', 'S17', 'S19', 'S3', 'S4', 'S5', 'S6', 'S9']
all_ls = []
for id, repeat in zip(id_list_fname, ls):
    res = [ele for ele in[id] for i in range(repeat)]
    all_ls.append(res)
```

Consequently, I would like the result to be a single flat list, which I achieved as below.

```
def flatten(lst):
    for item in lst:
        if isinstance(item, list):
            yield from flatten(item)
        else:
            yield item

final_output = list(flatten(all_ls))
```

Output of the `final_output`:

```
['S11', 'S11', 'S11', 'S11', 'S11', 'S11', 'S11', 'S15', 'S15', 'S15',
 'S16', 'S16', 'S16', 'S16', 'S16', 'S16', 'S16', 'S16', 'S16', 'S16',
 'S16', 'S17', 'S17', 'S17', 'S17', 'S17', 'S19', 'S19', 'S3', 'S3',
 'S3', 'S4', 'S4', 'S4', 'S4', 'S5', 'S5', 'S5', 'S5', 'S6', 'S6',
 'S9', 'S9', 'S9']
```

But I wonder there exist much more compact approach or technique such as `itertools` to have the repeat elements as what I achieved using the code snippet above.

Comment: Can you give a minimal example input and desired output?

Comment: Hi @lain, thanks for your interest in this OP. The example input and desired output already provided above.

Comment: @balandongiv I do not see the expected output.

Comment: Hi @yudhiesh, please check the amended version

Comment: The problem is that `all_ls.append(res)` appends the sub-list of `res` values as a single element, rather than appending all those values separately. For that, `.extend` works, as explained in the first linked duplicate. Otherwise,  the trick is to use a nested comprehension to encapsulate the work of the current list comprehension plus the `for id, repeat in zip(id_list_fname, ls):` loop, as in the second linked duplicate. Incidentally, the `ele for ele in[id]` part is useless; the shown list comprehension is equivalent to `[id for i in range(repeat)]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numpy has the [`repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) function:

```
np.repeat(id_list_fname, ls)
```

If you absolutely need a list:

```
np.repeat(id_list_fname, ls).tolist()
```

If you don't want to use numpy, keep in mind that python allows nested comprehensions, which are essentially multiple `for` loops creating a single flat list. Your original loop can be written as a flat one-liner:

```
[id for id, repeat in zip(id_list_fname, ls) for _ in range(repeat)]
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `itertools.chain` and `itertools.repeat`

```
from itertools import chain, repeat

ls = [7, 3, 11, 5, 2, 3, 4, 4, 2, 3]
id_list_fname = ['S11', 'S15', 'S16', 'S17', 'S19', 'S3', 'S4', 'S5', 'S6', 'S9']
res = list(chain.from_iterable(repeat(j, times = i) for i, j in zip(ls, id_list_fname)))

print(res)
```

Output

```
['S11', 'S11', 'S11', 'S11', 'S11', 'S11', 'S11', 'S15', 'S15', 'S15', 'S16', 'S16', 'S16', 'S16', 'S16', 'S16', 'S16', 'S16', 'S16', 'S16', 'S16', 'S17', 'S17', 'S17', 'S17', 'S17', 'S19', 'S19', 'S3', 'S3', 'S3', 'S4', 'S4', 'S4', 'S4', 'S5', 'S5', 'S5', 'S5', 'S6', 'S6', 'S9', 'S9', 'S9']
```

Answer (score 3):

With respect to your code, use `list.extend()` rather than `list.append()` when adding items into `all_ls`. This adds the items in the list to the existing list instead of adding the list to the existing list.

```
ls = [7, 3, 11, 5, 2, 3, 4, 4, 2, 3]
id_list_fname = ['S11', 'S15', 'S16', 'S17', 'S19', 'S3', 'S4', 'S5', 'S6', 'S9']
all_ls=[]
for s,repeat in zip(id_list_fname ,ls):
    res =  [ele for ele in [s] for i in range(repeat)]
    all_ls.extend(res)
```

Output

```
>>> all_ls
['S11', 'S11', 'S11', 'S11', 'S11', 'S11', 'S11', 'S15', 'S15', 'S15', 'S16', 'S16', 'S16', 'S16', 'S16', 'S16', 'S16', 'S16', 'S16', 'S16', 'S16', 'S17', 'S17', 'S17', 'S17', 'S17', 'S19', 'S19', 'S3', 'S3', 'S3', 'S4', 'S4', 'S4', 'S4', 'S5', 'S5', 'S5', 'S5', 'S6', 'S6', 'S9', 'S9', 'S9']
```

A better way is with a list comprehension - it can be done in one line:

```
>>> [item for n,s in zip(ls, id_list_fname) for item in [s]*n]
['S11', 'S11', 'S11', 'S11', 'S11', 'S11', 'S11', 'S15', 'S15', 'S15', 'S16', 'S16', 'S16', 'S16', 'S16', 'S16', 'S16', 'S16', 'S16', 'S16', 'S16', 'S17', 'S17', 'S17', 'S17', 'S17', 'S19', 'S19', 'S3', 'S3', 'S3', 'S4', 'S4', 'S4', 'S4', 'S5', 'S5', 'S5', 'S5', 'S6', 'S6', 'S9', 'S9', 'S9']
```

Comment: The dict comprehension can be replaced by `res = [id] * repeat`. `id` should not be used as a variable name in Python though, you are overwriting the built-in function `id`

Comment: @IainShelvington: what dict comprehension? Fair enough with `id`, just copied from OP. Updated.

Comment: @IainShelvington: also, minimal changes to OP's code helps OP to understand the difference. I have added a better list comprehension to perform same task in one line.

Comment: Thanks @mhawke, extra knowledge obained from your post.

Comment: @mhawke I meant list comprehension, apologies

Comment: @IainShelvington: oh, reasonable mistake. Thanks for your feedback.